# Is it possible to add QTreeWidgetItem to QTableWidgetItem?

Tags: c++, qt

I have QTableWidget and I interested in how I can add QTreeWidget item into 3rd column in table? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I do it:

```
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() - 1, 3, new QTreeWidget());
auto widget = dynamic_cast<QTreeWidget*>(ui->tableWidget->cellWidget(ui->tableWidget->rowCount() - 1, 3));
widget->setHeaderHidden(true);

QTreeWidgetItem * topLevel = new QTreeWidgetItem();
topLevel->setText(0, "This is top level");
widget->addTopLevelItem(topLevel);
```